# align text in middle of a column in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am HTML structure where i need to place logo in one column & Title in other other column .

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=[Logo 1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns ">This is the Title</div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=[Logo 2]" />
    </div>
    <div class="large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns ">This is the Title</div>
</div>
```

Logo can be of different dimension as show in the example above.

I want to align the title. Here is a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/15/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/16/).

CSS

```
.mainCnt {
    display: table;
}
.mainCnt .columns {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none !important
}
```

You can remove `!important` by giving complete CSS hierarchy.

Added a class `mainCnt` to `row` so it will not affect anywhere else.

Comment: If  Ido it this way then i loose the responsive features, I had tried `display:table;` but design breaks on smaller screens. see what happens to your fiddle eample.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/17/)

If you know the size of the logos then you can just go with line-height and align text in the middle..\

As first logo has a height of 100px set line-height of that corresponding title to 100px;

```
.div1{
line-height:100px;    
}
```

similarly for div2

```
.div2{
line-height:69px;
}
```

If you want to have text aligned horizontally as well just add

```
text-align:center;
```

to both the classes

Comment: This is if i have two elements, But i have different logos and each has different height & width. Doesnt that mean i have to create a sepearte css for them.

Comment: Ya check demo ..it has two classes ..one for each logo